# add drop down in a drop down menu

Tags: html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm want to add a drop down or a side menu to the first drop down that contains GRAD and DC. Anyone have any ideas? HTML code is below: I did read somewhere that you can't do this?  If you put this in JSBin, select Bootstrap latest to see the results.

```
    <div class="nav">
     <h1>ONE STOP SHOP</h1>
     <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      Fact Sheets <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">GRAD</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">DC</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      Shared Files <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">GRAD</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">DC</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">RC BAK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">RC VIS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">RC NFC</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">RC MER</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't add a drop down per se (with bootstrap) but you should be able to do it with jquery or add in a flyout menu. As it is you can add elements easy enough http://output.jsbin.com/vohetomeya/

Comment: You could always just code it yourself and add in some css. See http://ambercomplementarytherapy.com/ and have a look at the css (applicable to the services menu)

Comment: from .nav {
 list-style: none;
 *zoom: 1;
 background: #66e6d9;
 -webkit-padding-start: 8px !important;
 -moz-padding-start: 8px !important
}
to 
ul.parent {
 display: inline-block
}